How to PIVOT data in snowflake by using ANY without having quotes for 'Column_Names'
How to PIVOT data in snowflake by using ANY without having quotes for 'Column_Names'.
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE quarterly_sales(
  empid INT, 
  amount INT, 
  quarter TEXT)
  AS SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 10000, '2023_Q1'),    (1, 400, '2023_Q1'),    (2, 4500, '2023_Q1'),    (2, 35000, '2023_Q1'),    (1, 5000, '2023_Q2'),    (1, 3000, '2023_Q2'),
    (2, 200, '2023_Q2'),    (2, 90500, '2023_Q2'),    (1, 6000, '2023_Q3'),    (1, 5000, '2023_Q3'),    (2, 2500, '2023_Q3'),    (2, 9500, '2023_Q3'),
    (1, 8000, '2023_Q4'),    (1, 10000, '2023_Q4'),    (2, 800, '2023_Q4'),    (2, 4500, '2023_Q4');

SELECT *
  FROM quarterly_sales
    PIVOT(SUM(amount) FOR quarter IN (ANY ORDER BY quarter))
  ORDER BY empid;


Hi - please don’t use images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Format code as code. Provide sample data and the result you want to achieve, both formatted as tables

so the example SQL is striaght from the doc's https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot but I also note the code is not working on my  snowflake instance ether.

@SimeonPilgrim - the code is working but I don't want the column names with single quotes when the pivot is done.

@NickW Sure thing. I just wanted to show in image that how quotes are generated when pivot is done . And need an alternative solution to it

right, so the joy of asking questions, if you do not show what you want, the "without quoted names" can be read to bind to "with out have to name them column" which as you note the ANY provides.

Righto so the problem I was having was ANY does not work on CTE:
with quarterly_sales(empid, amount, quarter) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10000, '2023_Q1'),    
        (1, 400, '2023_Q1'),    
        (2, 4500, '2023_Q1'),    
        (2, 35000, '2023_Q1'),    
        (1, 5000, '2023_Q2'),    
        (1, 3000, '2023_Q2'),
        (2, 200, '2023_Q2')
)
SELECT *
  FROM quarterly_sales as qs
    PIVOT(sum(amount) FOR qs.quarter IN (
      SELECT distinct quarter from quarterly_sales order by quarter )
    ) 
  ORDER BY empid;

but if you create the TABLE as the problem notes it works, but has the name of the column in quotes. As is not wanted.
Of interest if you do it the old school way, with a named column:
SELECT *
  FROM quarterly_sales as qs
    PIVOT(sum(amount) FOR qs.quarter IN (
      '2023_Q1' )
    ) 
  ORDER BY empid;

you get quotes:

So this is not an ANY problem, but a PIVOT problem.
So next I tested can I use the result without quotes via a RESULT_SCAN:
select sum(2023_Q1)
from table(result_scan('01b59536-0205-9509-0005-aae70008901e'));

shows undersore is an invalid token:

Syntax error: unexpected '_Q1'. (line 35)

select sum("2023_Q1")
from table(result_scan('01b59536-0205-9509-0005-aae70008901e'));


Error: invalid identifier '"2023_Q1"' (line 35)

so sure enough, the single quote is required:
select sum("'2023_Q1'")
from table(result_scan('01b59536-0205-9509-0005-aae70008901e'));

but agian, this is a PIVOT thing, not an ANY thing.

Now if you know what your columns are you can clean them up:
SELECT *
  FROM quarterly_sales as qs
    PIVOT(sum(amount) FOR qs.quarter IN (
      '2023_Q1' )
    ) as p(empid, "2023_Q1_NO_QUOTE")
  ORDER BY empid;


So we are back to, if you know how things are, you can do the things required to be correct, and if you want one block of code to handle all things, hoop jumping is the life for you.
